# PDF.JS with CANVAS Draw : Draw rectangle in canvas with PDF loaded using pdf.js

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, canvas, pdf.js

I need to

1) First  select PDF

2) Load it using PDF.js (select page) and

3) Draw rectangle on it using canvas.

For that I was able to make, most of my requirements but when i draw rectangle on canvas PDF, then design gets disturb and creates multiple rectangle instead of single.

I just need one rectangle. For example this rectangle design is disturbing creates multiple. Is it possible to create only 1 rectangle ?

Issue Ref. http://prntscr.com/n4h1np

**Sample Demo** : https://testchat32.tk/v/PDF/03.html

Any help or suggestion on this are most welcome.

Thanks in advance.

```js
                 /*load pdf*/
            var __PDF_DOC,
                __CURRENT_PAGE,
                __TOTAL_PAGES,
                __PAGE_RENDERING_IN_PROGRESS = 0,
                __CANVAS = $('#pdf-canvas').get(0),
                __CANVAS_CTX = __CANVAS.getContext('2d');
            
            function showPDF(pdf_url) {
                $("#pdf-loader").show();
                PDFJS.getDocument({ url: pdf_url }).then(function(pdf_doc) {
                    
                    __PDF_DOC = pdf_doc;
                    __TOTAL_PAGES = __PDF_DOC.numPages;
                    
                    // Hide the pdf loader and show pdf container in HTML
                    $("#pdf-loader").hide();
                    $("#pdf-contents").show();
                    $("#pdf-total-pages").text(__TOTAL_PAGES);
            
                    // Show the first page
                    showPage(1);
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    // If error re-show the upload button
                    $("#pdf-loader").hide();
                    $("#upload-button").show();
                    
                    //alert(error.message);
                });;
            }
            
            function showPage(page_no) {
                __PAGE_RENDERING_IN_PROGRESS = 1;
                __CURRENT_PAGE = page_no;
            
                // Disable Prev & Next buttons while page is being loaded
                $("#pdf-next, #pdf-prev").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            
                // While page is being rendered hide the canvas and show 
                $("#pdf-canvas").hide();
                $("#page-loader").show();
            
                // Update current page in HTML
                $("#pdf-current-page").text(page_no);
                
                jQuery("#pdf_page_no").val(page_no);
                jQuery(".pdf_page_no").val(page_no);
                
                // Fetch the page
                __PDF_DOC.getPage(page_no).then(function(page) {
                    // As the canvas is of a fixed width we need to set the scale of the viewport accordingly
                    var scale_required = __CANVAS.width / page.getViewport(1).width;
            
                    // Get viewport of the page at required scale
                    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale_required);
            
                    // Set canvas height
                    __CANVAS.height = viewport.height;
            
                    var renderContext = {
                        canvasContext: __CANVAS_CTX,
                        viewport: viewport
                    };
                    
                    // Render the page contents in the canvas
                    page.render(renderContext).then(function() {
                        __PAGE_RENDERING_IN_PROGRESS = 0;
            
                        // Re-enable Prev & Next buttons
                        $("#pdf-next, #pdf-prev").removeAttr('disabled');
            
                        // Show the canvas and hide the page loader
                        $("#pdf-canvas").show();
                        $("#page-loader").hide();
                    });
                });
            }
            
            // Upon click this should should trigger click on the #file-to-upload 
            // This is better than showing the not-good-looking file input element
            $("#upload-button").on('click', function() {
                $("#file-to-upload").trigger('click');
            });
            
            // When user chooses a PDF file
            $("#file-input").on('change', function() {
                // Validate whether PDF
                if(['application/pdf'].indexOf($("#file-input").get(0).files[0].type) == -1) {
                    alert('Error : Not a PDF');
                    return; // Viral vvvvvvvv
                }
            
                
                // Send the object url of the pdf
                showPDF(URL.createObjectURL($("#file-input").get(0).files[0]));
                jQuery('#pdf-contents').removeClass('test');
                $('#pdf-signatur-popup').modal('show');
            });
            
            // Previous page of the PDF
            $("#pdf-prev").on('click', function() {
                if(__CURRENT_PAGE != 1)
                    showPage(--__CURRENT_PAGE);
            });
            
            // Next page of the PDF
            $("#pdf-next").on('click', function() {
                if(__CURRENT_PAGE != __TOTAL_PAGES)
                    showPage(++__CURRENT_PAGE);
            });
            /*load pdf*/
            
            
            
            
            /* Draw On PDF ST */
            "use strict";
            requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
            const canvas = document.getElementById("pdf-canvas");
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            const storedRects = [];
            const baseImage = loadImage("");
            var refresh = true;
            const rect = (() => {
                var x1, y1, x2, y2;
                var show = false;
                function fix() {
                    rect.x = Math.min(x1, x2);
                    rect.y = Math.min(y1, y2);
                    rect.w = Math.max(x1, x2) - Math.min(x1, x2);
                    rect.h = Math.max(y1, y2) - Math.min(y1, y2);
                    
            
                     jQuery("body").click(function(e) {
                        console.log(rect.x+'='+rect.y+'='+rect.w+'='+rect.h);
                         $('#output').html('current x : '+rect.x+', current y : '+rect.y+', width : '+rect.w+', height : '+rect.h);
                         
                        if (e.target.id == "pdf-canvas") {
                            ddrag();
                            jQuery(".position_x").val(rect.x);
                            jQuery(".position_y").val(rect.y);
                            jQuery(".position_w").val(rect.w);
                            jQuery(".position_h").val(rect.h);
                        }
                     });
                }
            
                function draw(ctx) { ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h) }
                const rect = {x : 0, y : 0, w : 0, h : 0,  draw};
                const API = {
                    restart(point) {
                        x2 = x1 = point.x;
                        y2 = y1 = point.y;
                        fix();
                        show = true;
                    },
                    update(point) {
                        x2 = point.x;
                        y2 = point.y;
                        fix();
                        show = true;
                    },
                    toRect() {
                        show = false;
                        return Object.assign({}, rect);
                    },
                    draw(ctx) {
                        if (show) { rect.draw(ctx) }
                    },
                    show : false,
                }
                return API;
            })();
            
            function loadImage(url) {
                const image = new Image();
                image.src = url;
                image.onload = () => refresh = true;
                return image;
            }
            
            const mouse = {
                button : false,
                x : 0,
                y : 0,
                down : false,
                up : false,
                element : null,
                event(e) {
                    const m = mouse;
                    m.bounds = m.element.getBoundingClientRect();
                    m.x = e.pageX - m.bounds.left - scrollX;
                    m.y = e.pageY - m.bounds.top - scrollY;
                    const prevButton = m.button;
                    m.button = e.type === "mousedown" ? true : e.type === "mouseup" ? false : mouse.button;
                    if (!prevButton && m.button) { m.down = true }
                    if (prevButton && !m.button) { m.up = true }
                },
                start(element) {
                    mouse.element = element;
                    "down,up,move".split(",").forEach(name => document.addEventListener("mouse" + name, mouse.event));
                }
            }
            
            mouse.start(canvas);
            function draw() {
                
                const storedRects = [];
                ctx.restore();
                
                ctx.drawImage(baseImage, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.width);
                ctx.lineWidth = 1;
                ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow";
                storedRects.forEach(rect => rect.draw(ctx));
                ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
                rect.draw(ctx);
            }
            function mainLoop() {
                if (refresh || mouse.down || mouse.up || mouse.button) {
                    refresh = false;
                    if (mouse.down) {
                        mouse.down = false;
                        rect.restart(mouse);
                    } else if (mouse.button) {
                        rect.update(mouse);
                    } else if (mouse.up) {
                        mouse.up = false;
                        rect.update(mouse);
                        //storedRects.push(rect.toRect());
                    }
                    draw();
                }
                requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop)
            }
            
            function clearCanvas (canvas)
            {
                const storedRects = [];
                //alert(jQuery(".position_x").val());
                jQuery('#pdf-contents').removeClass('test');
                
            
                //alert(URL.createObjectURL($("#file-input").get(0).files[0]))
                showPDF(URL.createObjectURL($("#file-input").get(0).files[0]));
                
                
            } 
            function ddrag(){
                
                 //const storedRects = [];
                 jQuery('.test #pdf-canvas').mousedown(function(){ 
                 console.log(jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr('class'));
                if(jQuery(this).parent().parent().attr('class')=="test"){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
                });
                jQuery('#pdf-contents').addClass('test');
                
                    //return false; 
                
                
            }
            
              /* Draw On PDF EN */
```

```html
                         <!--jquery_ST-->
                    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <!--jquery_EN-->
                    <!--bootstrap_ST-->
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                    <!--bootstrap_EN-->
                    <!--PDF_JS-->
                    <script src="https://testchat32.tk/v/PDF/pdf.js" ></script>
                    <script src="https://testchat32.tk/v/PDF/pdf.worker.js" ></script>
                    <!--PDF_JS-->
                    
                    <div class="card-body b-t">
                      <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frm_tech_msg" name="frm_tech_msg" class="form-horizontal"  action="{{ route('get/pdf') }}" method="post" style="width:100%;">
                     
                        <input type="hidden" name="media_type" id="media_type" class="media_type" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="position_x" id="position_x" class="position_x" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="position_y" id="position_y" class="position_y" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="position_w" id="position_w" class="position_w" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="position_h" id="position_h" class="position_h" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="pdf_page_no" id="pdf_page_no" class="pdf_page_no" value="1">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="clip-upload"> 
                            
                            <!--label for="file-input"--> 
                            
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="media-selection" id="media-selection"><i class="fa fa-paperclip fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <input type="file" class="file-input hide" name="file-input" id="file-input">
                            <!--   onchange="readURL(this);"--> 
                            
                            <!--/label-->
                            
                            <ul class="media-selection-option" style="padding:50px 0 0 100px;">
                              <li data-id="1" accept-file=".pdf"><span><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
                                <label for="file-input" style="cursor:pointer;">Select PDF</label>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- The Modal -->
                    <div class="modal pdf-signatur-popup" id="pdf-signatur-popup">
                      <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content" style="width:630px;"> 
                          
                          <!-- Modal Header -->
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Drag to select signature area</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <div id="output"></div>
                          </div>
                          
                          <!-- Modal body -->
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="pdf-main-container" class="pdf-main-container">
                              <div id="pdf-loader">Loading document ...</div>
                              <div id="pdf-contents">
                                <div id="pdf-meta">
                                  <div id="pdf-buttons">
                                    <button id="pdf-prev">Previous</button>
                                    <button onclick="clearCanvas()" class="test1212 btn-reload">Reload PDF/Reassign area</button>
                                    <button id="pdf-next">Next</button>
                                    <br>
                                  </div>
                                  <div id="page-count-container">Page
                                    <div id="pdf-current-page"></div>
                                    of
                                    <div id="pdf-total-pages"></div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="add-remove">
                                  <canvas id="pdf-canvas" width="595"  style="border:1px solid #000000;cursor:crosshair"></canvas>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- The Modal -->
```

Comment: did you ever fixed it?

Comment: Yes i found solution to avoid multiple duplicate line draw. I customized draw function like following and added clear previous line stroke. 

 function draw(ctx) { 
  ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h) 
  }

Comment: i got the same issue, I want to draw only one rectangle at a time over a pdf,  when i draw new rectangle the old rectangle should be remove, but it is not happening

Comment: here is my question link, if you have any answer then it would be helpful for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58590845/draw-rectangle-in-canvas-with-loaded-pdf-file-using-pdf-js